# lib/spring/application.rb:248:in `start_with?': incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails g model mapを仕様としたところ

例のエラーが出ました。
encoding の種類の異なる文字列を連結させようとすると起きるエラーで在るということはわかったので、色々やってみたのですが、
具体的には下記のほかにどのようなことを施せば良いのでしょうか。

log

```
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:270:in `block (3 levels) in shush_backtraces'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:270:in `reject!'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:270:in `ensure in block (2 levels) in shush_backtraces'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in shush_backtraces'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `rescue in load_dependency'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:184:in `block in serve'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `fork'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:132:in `block in run'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:126:in `loop'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:126:in `run'
from /Users/Sean/Documents/今後処理/psara-institute/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
from /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

config/environment.rb

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
# Initialize the Rails application.

Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8

Rails.application.initialize!
... 続く
```

Comment: パスに`今後処理`というマルチバイト文字が含まれているからです。
ディレクトリ名を変更すれば解決しますが、変更せずに対応したい、ということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、良くmacのデフォルトのディレクトリex 書類　だと
英語表記は Documents 日本語表記は書類となっていると思うのですが、どうすればそのようにできるのでしょうか。

また他に解決方法が在りましたら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

マルチバイトが普及した現在においても、パス名に日本語を使うのは未だにオススメできません。

よって、ディレクトリ名を英語とし、表示を日本語にする、という下記について回答します。
ruby への回答ではないため、題名を変更されるのが宜しいかもしれません。

> 良くmacのデフォルトのディレクトリex 書類　だと 英語表記は Documents
>   日本語表記は書類となっていると思うのですが、どうすればそのようにできるのでしょうか

1. ディレクトリのプロパティから、アイコンの変更をする
2. ディレクトリ内に、desktop.ini が作成されるので、
3. LocalizedResourceName に、日本語名を入力する
4. エクスプローラを開き直す、最新の情報に更新、などで、表示が変わることが確認できます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
パス名は、`dummy` ですが、表示名は、`ダミーフォルダ` になっています。

desktop.ini が見えない場合は、フォルダオプションの
- `隠しファイル……を表示する`
- `保護されたオペレーティング・システムファイルを表示しない`
の2項目を確認してください。

アイコンの変更は必須ではないのですが、
手動で desktop.ini を作成すると、
打ち間違えなどでハマる可能性があるので、
こちらで書いています。